# Can a content be cached even if the max-age header is not set and vice versa?

Tags: cache, http

As far as I understand, when a request is made for the **very first time**, the browser will download the resource from the server.

If the `Cache-Control: private,max-age=value` `header` is present, then it can cache it for `value` seconds.

This much is clear.

However,

1. For a cached resource with `max-age` set, in the **second request** for the same resource, why is there a `Response` shown in the profiler? Technically there shouldn't be a `Response` right? Is it from the `resource cache`? Assuming that it is a pseudo response from the clients
   caching mechanism, should that `Response` have a `Cache-Control`
   header or not (remember the first request already informed that)?
2. If the a client sends a `no-cache` in the request and it gets a response with `max-age`, how
   does that work for the next request? Will it do a round-trip to check if the content has not changed? How about server using `no-cache` and `max-age` together - is that possible?
3. <s>Sometimes I have seen that caching works even without the
   `Cache-Control: private,max-age=86400` header. However, in this scenario, I see that there was a `Etag` in the previous response and client sends it back in `If-None-Match` in the next request and the HTTP response is `304`. Is that normal?</s> Please see [What happens if you don't set cache-control header?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/111298/what-happens-if-you-dont-set-cache-control-header/111299#111299)
4. Last but not least, in `IE 11`'s `Developer Tools`, why do we see `304 (not modified)`
   instead of `200 (disk cache)` for a cached resource? We are doing a right click `Refresh` or <kbd>F5</kbd> to test what is happening. In a normal scenario, does IE takes the content from the disk cache just like all other browsers?

I am trying to troubleshoot a `cache` issue in `IE 11` where despite the `Cache-Control: private,max-age=86400` in the  `Response Header`, the content is still downloaded from the server. There is a `Cache-Control: no-cache` in the `Request Header` though.

It happens when we browse normally as well as with the `F12 Developer Tools`.

Our Network Topology is something like `Client <-> F5 <-> App Server`.

I am also reading the [HTTP Caching article in Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/http-caching) but things are not so clear.