# What happens if you don't set cache-control header?

Tags: cache, http, cache-control

What happens if you don't set the `cache-control` header? Does HTTP specify a default behaviour that clients should follow or is it up to the clients to decide?

In Chrome, I have seen some Javascript requests that have no `cache-control` headers showing up as `200 (from disk cache)`. Is Chrome optimizing this?

In IE, I have seen it show up as a `304 (not modified)`.

How do I understand this better?

Comment: "no cache headers" meaning no Cache-Control header, or really no cache headers? Cache-control is not the only header that affects caching. Most web servers will send Last Modified headers for static assets like Javascript files.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

If there is no `Cache-Control` header and no `Expires` header, but there is a `Last-Modified` header (which most web servers send by default for static assets), [most browsers](https://www.mnot.net/blog/2017/03/16/browser-caching) will use *heuristic freshness* to determine how long to cache that asset for.

The typical calculation for this (which is the one suggested by [RFC 7234](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-4.2.2)) is:

```
(current time - last modified time) / 10
```

So, for example, if the last modified time for an image states it was last changed 60 days ago, a browser might decide it could reasonably use the locally cached version of that image for 6 days before checking for a new version.

Note that in most cases, if you hit refresh, you are *telling* the browser to fetch a fresh version, so in that situation this logic wouldn't apply.

## Freshness as determined by actual browsers:

- [Chrome still uses](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/refs/tags/87.0.4280.67/net/http/http_response_headers.cc#1082) the old "10% of time since last_modified", matching the RFC's suggestion
- [Same goes for Safari](https://github.com/WebKit/webkit/blob/950143da027e80924b4bb86defa8a3f21fd3fb1e/Source/WebCore/platform/network/CacheValidation.cpp#L140)
- [Firefox nowadays uses](https://github.com/mozilla/gecko-dev/blob/esr78/netwerk/protocol/http/nsHttpResponseHead.cpp#L704) `min(one week, (current time - last modified time) / 10)`. So freshness is *never* more than one week

Comment: And if there is no `Last-Modified` header?

Comment: This is the answer I've been looking for. I am curious, however, what various browsers have as default.

Comment: @bertonc96 It seems to be 0 in that case. See for example [this](https://github.com/mozilla/gecko-dev/blob/esr78/netwerk/protocol/http/nsHttpResponseHead.cpp#L711).